# Securing the Server Hello in TLS 1.3

Tags: encryption, tls, public-key-infrastructure

I've been trying to better understand TLS, and am stuck on one point with TLS 1.3.  I understand that the Client makes an assumption regarding which Cipher Suite the Server will select, and includes a key share along with the Client Random in the Client Hello.

In the Server Hello, assuming it agrees to the Client's selection, sends back a Certificate and the Server Random.  Then the Client and Server generate session keys based on these two exchanges, thus 1.3 is much faster.

What I don't fully understand is how this is safe from eavesdropping.  The Client Hello, as it is the first message, lacks encryption, so that knowledge is available.  Does the Server Hello encrypt itself with a public key from the client?

My confusion stems from comparing two sources of info...

1. From this [CloudFlare](https://blog.cloudflare.com/tls-1-3-overview-and-q-and-a/) blog, it sounds like the Server Hello encrypts with a public key from the client.
2. [This guide](https://tls13.xargs.org/) makes no mention of the hellos being encrypted.  It instead shows the session keys being generated using a hash of the hellos and the complimentary key sets, i.e. the Client creates a key with its private, the server public, and the hash, while the server uses its private, the client public, and the hash.

Does anyone know if the Server Hello is an encrypted response, or if possession of the complimentary keys is the crucial step to the Hello's being secure? Thanks!

Comment: The private keys of the client and the server are kept secret. The fact that an eavesdropper knows everything else does not matter, because she needs at least one private key in order to produce the shared secret. Maybe this will help you understand better: https://tls13.xargs.org/

Comment: Thanks @Spyros, that link is actually the second one in my post. It does show the ingredients to a session key being `private key + shared public key + hash`. Contrasting that with the CloudFlare post, which implies the Server Hello is encrypted via the Client public key.  I was not sure which was more accurate.

Certainly the tls13.xargs.org is a more thorough guide, but I don't understand why the randoms are even used if they are unencrypted, instead of just using `private key + shared public key`, but I imagine that is a cryptography based question with a great deal of math.

Comment: ah, silly me, sorry about that. A note though, on cloudflare's blog article it does not say that the *whole* ServerHello is encrypted, but only part of it; this seems to agree with *https://cabulous.medium.com/tls-1-2-andtls-1-3-handshake-walkthrough-4cfd0a798164* and *https://commandlinefanatic.com/cgi-bin/showarticle.cgi?article=art080* which makes me believe that it is correct

Comment: @Spyros That blog is about (significant) differences between 1.2 and 1.3, but quite sloppy about each. In modernish 1.2 server sends _4 to 6_ messages grouped into one 'flight': ServerHello (containing ciphersuite), Certificate, optional CertStatus if stapling, ServerKeyExchange (containing DH keyshare _and_ signature), optional and rare CertReq, ServerDone. In 1.3 it sends 5 to 7: ServerHello (containing ciphersuite _and_ DH keyshare), optional CCS, EncryptedExtensions, rare CertReq, Certificate, CertVerify, Finished, with EncExt and everything after it encrypted.

Comment: Thank you both, I appreciate the help. For anyone that may stumble upon this in the future, I found this video quite useful: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NmM9HA2MQGI.  It does not specifically mention 1.3, but makes it clear how the exchange can operate in 1.3 (which, as noted above, is more in line with that second source)